# How to model this data structure in redis?

Tags: php, caching, nosql, redis

I have two tables in mysql, tasks and users. How do I model it in redis ? which data structure to use ?

E.g.,

```
tasks
-------------------------------------------
id  name assigned_to cretead_at
-------------------------------------------
1   task1  1          2012-09-10 00:00:00
-------------------------------------------
2   task2  2          2013-09-11 00:00:00
--------------------------------------------


users
-------------------
id  name email 
-------------------
1   user1  abc@xyz.com          
--------------------
2   user2  efg@xyz.com          
-------------------
```

My requirement is, I have user id and wish to load all fields in to php array. I don't want to fetch single field like only name of user. I want to load users all info in php array for particular user id e.g.

```
$user[1] = array("name" => "user1", "email" => "abc@xyz.com");
```

It would be better if I could categories it under different sets like "users" and "tasks" instead of storing it in many keys.

Comment: Well that depends - Wnat structure is the data that you want to display to the user?

Comment: So your only use case is to fetch a user by `assigned_to`? That's the _only_ think your application does?

Comment: This is just an similar use case of my application. I want to cache users data in redis and fetch it by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is a Key:Value storage system, so you can store (and get) value by key.

To store all data in a group by categories (user, taks, etc) you can use [List](http://redis.io/commands#list). For example with phpredis:

```
// To store lset(key index value)
$redis->lSet('users', $user[$id]['id'], json_encode($user[$id]));
// To get lget(key, index)
$redis->lGet('users', $id)
```

Comment: I have users, tasks and many other entities which I may wish to cache.  So I am looking for categorizing it, lets say by keys "users", "tasks" etc. I understand its not database, I wish to cache some records for different entities.

Comment: You can serialize all that you want, so if you want a big record of users you can do $redis->set($id, json_encode($user[$id])); to store one user for key, or $redis->set('users', json_encode($user)); The max size of a string is of 512Mb so if your user table is lager I suggest you to use sets (http://redis.io/commands#set).

Comment: I dont want to use  $redis->set($id, json_encode($user[$id])); as I want to categorize it for "users", "tasks" and so on.. I want to use  $redis->set('users', json_encode($user)); but I how can I access user by user's id ? The structure I want is "users" --> user_id --> json_encode($user); How can I achieve this ?

Comment: with list: $redis->lSet('users', $user[$id]['id'],  json_encode($user[$id])); and get with $redis->lGet('users', $id); /* 'X' */